# what's the meaning of "the first [number]"

Tags: meaning

I usually come across a sentence like "the first [number]". 
For example,

> If the number of questions is 100, a student submitted answers to the first 10 questions.

I don't exactly get the meaning of "the first 10" in this sentence. Does this means that the student submitted answers numbering 1 ~ 10?

Comment: The first 10 questions are questions #1, #2, #3 ... #10.

Comment: How can I represent #5 ~ #10? "a student submitted answers to the fifth to 10 questions." is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The first ten" means the first, the second, ..., the ninth, and the tenth.

If you want to concisely say "the fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, and tenth", it's probably best to say "fifth through tenth", as in, "A student submitted answers to the fifth through tenth questions."

Comment: Using "through" in that way is North American usage.